# ehcache RMI config to spring

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I'm trying to move the creation of Cache that uses RMI from `ehcache.xml` file to a Spring xml.
It wasn't a problem to just create a `EhCacheFactoryBean` but how does `RMICacheReplicatorFactory` definition suppose to/can be implemented?
Here is how it looks in `ehcache.xml` file.

Many thanks,
Idan

```
<cache name="MyCache1"
    maxElementsInMemory="1000"
    eternal="false"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
    timeToLiveSeconds="3000"
    timeToIdleSeconds="3000"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">

    <!-- RMI replication listener -->
    <cacheEventListenerFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
        properties="replicateAsynchronously=true,
             replicatePuts=true,
             replicatePutsViaCopy=true,
             replicateUpdates=true,
             replicateUpdatesViaCopy=true,
             replicateRemovals=true" />

    <!-- RMI Cache bootstrap -->
    <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory"
        properties="bootstrapAsynchronously=true, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"
        propertySeparator="," />
</cache>
```

Comment: Hows the beans definitions and does it output an error, this question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Spring 3 there is a `cacheEventListeners` property of type `Set<CacheEventListener>` for the `EhCacheFactoryBean` (see https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6234). When using 2.5 you could extend `EhCacheFactoryBean` yourself like [shown here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5641).